# Is it ever unsafe to compress an EC point?

Tags: elliptic-curves, compression

I am working with a library that outputs EC points in uncompressed form.  To save space, I'm considering modifying said library to use compressed EC points.  Assuming that I keep track of the sign bit prior to compression, is there any risk in compressing said point?

I read this [Q and related answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8914/371), but want to ensure that I may not be opening the door for other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a quadratic non-residue in order to decompress the points, and

there is no known deterministic algorithm that will provably find one efficiently.

Also, if you allow both sign bits for $\: y=0 \:$ or the point-at-infinity,

then you will lose [non-malleability](http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~hoeteck/pubs/cpa-nm-tcc08.pdf#page=9) and [strong unforgeability](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/cse207/s-ds.pdf).

Comment: Huh?  To decompress a point, you need to compute a modular square-root.  If $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, that's easy to do.  If one were to work in a prime field with $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then, yes, it's a bit more difficult, and you will need to find a quadratic nonresidue (which isn't that complicated -- pick random points until you find one works); however we generally work in fields with characteristic 3 mod 4.

Comment: @poncho Curve25519 has $p \equiv 5 \pmod 8$. P-224 has $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. But there are efficient algorithms for computer square-roots in both of those fields.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: actually, there's a deterministic solution in that case as well; it's a tad more complex than the 3 mod 4 solution, but still works.  What's tougher is the 1 mod 8 case...

Comment: Cipolla-Lehmer modular square root works for all prime moduli and is easier to implement compared to Shanks-Tonelli.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

I would argue the opposite: it's *safer* to compress a point.

The reason is fairly simple.   During decompression- whose most expensive operation is a modular square root - your are guaranteeing that the resulting point either is on the curve, zero or infinity.

One of the most frequent errors in elliptic curve operations is failing to properly validate a point before operating on it.   The most public example of this is the Bluetooth pairing vulnerability - which, had it used compressed points, would not have been vulnerable to MITM attacks.

While validation is less expensive than decompression - it's one of those "seemingly optional" steps that people can forget to do.   With compressed points there's no option.