# Is it secure to ECDSA-sign a public key without hashing it first?

Tags: hash, elliptic-curves, dsa

I am trying to sign an ECDH public key with ECDSA. However, my hardware does not allow me to implement a hash algorithm, considering I am running out of memory already.

Therefore, I am currently just passing the ECDH public key as the message to be signed to the sign function without any hashing beforehand, which is usually advised in any algorithm explanation (see chapter 6.4, http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf).

I have yet to find any evidence or analysis about possible security implications of skipping the hashing step. My intuition would say, that hashing the message serves as a way to blur the original message, essentially avoiding any retracing if the algorithm was somehow compromised.

If this is the case, would it be applicable to simply leave out the hash in this case, considering I am sending the ECDH public key in plain text over the wire anyways?

Comment: What are you actually planning as input? The X coordinate of the public key? Inputting a DER encoded key *definitely* doesn't sound like a good option.

Comment: I was planning to input my 64 byte public key. If both me and the client have access to the equal hardcoded ECDSA keys, we should be able to verify, that no man in the middle attack happened, as the message contains the public key as well as the signature for it, which the client could then easily verify.

Comment: ECDSA is only allowing values smaller than the field size to be used as input for the hash. If I'm not mistaken the hash is part of the security proof of ECDSA, but I'm not sure if this will directly influence it as the X coordinate (which could be sufficient) is probably random and large enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [FIPS 186-4, section 6.4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=38)

> An approved hash function, as specified in FIPS 180, **shall** be used during the generation of digital signatures.

Thus if the hashing step was removed, then this is no longer [ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm). Let's call the resulting Modified signature scheme MECDSA.

MECDSA has a potential weakness: it is easily exhibited a valid MECDSA signature for message(s) $m\equiv0\pmod n$: signature $(r,s)$ with $r=s=x_A\bmod n$, where $x_A$ is the $x$ coordinate of the signer's public key $Q_A$; at verification we get $z=0$, $u_1=0$, $u_2=1$, $u_1\times G+u_2\times Q_A\,=\,Q_A$, hence $r\equiv x_1\bmod n$ and the signature verifies. With true ECDSA, it is computationally infeasible to exhibit a message hashing to $0\pmod n$, making this a non-issue.

**Update:** things get much worse: we can efficiently exhibit an arbitrary number of (message, signature) pairs passing verification (but there's no control on the message); see [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/49956/555).

It is not quite clear if MECDSA signs an integer $m$ or a bitstring; and the maximum $m$, or the maximum size of the bitstring:

- If $m$ was an unbounded integer, the signature for $m$ would also be valid for $m+n$, where $n$ is the order of the group ($n\approx 2^{256}-2^{224}$ for curve P-256). To solve this, we'd need to restrict to $0<m<n$.
- If $m$ was a bitstring of exactly as many bits as $n$, then we would also have a number of bitstrings with interchangeable signatures (about $2^{224}$ such 256-bit bitstring pairs for curve P-256).

In either case, we are slightly in trouble if the public key to sign is using the same curve as used for the ECDSA signature: the usual ("uncompressed") form of a public key is twice as wide as $n$ is; and even with [point compression](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8914/555) (which is not all that usual, and is not considered by FIPS 186-4), a public key is one bit more than $n$ is. In order to solve this, we'd need to restrict the allowable public keys (e.g. with sign bit clear, and the $x$ coordinate less than $n$, thus removing very slightly more than half of the valid public keys).

An important other issue is that signatures of public keys, also known as public key certificates, typically need attributes, like who they belong to. We could spare a few more bits for a serial number at the cost of further restrictions in the public key, but each bit spared doubles the difficulty of generating a public/private key pair. Thus in the end we might need to sign two messages instead of one, with something to link the two signed messages. That's feasible, but hairy!

With such restriction to signing messages $m$ with $0<m<n$, and non-standard form of public key or/and certificate content, carefully enforced/compensated at verification, MECDSA could be used to sign a public key. But it is clumsy, and is it safe? I'm not entirely sure. That's not a well-studied problem. I would never prescribe it, and would feel very uncomfortable endorsing or doing it, for lack of positive security argument, and because of the usability issues. Hashing is cheap (it can be done in less than 1 kByte of code), and signing hashed message is the way to go.

Addition: here is a tiny (1.2 kiB) implementation of SHA-256

```
// tinysha256 - a public domain, compact implementation of sha256 
// input is limited to 0 to 0xffffffff octets(s) in memory
// gcc 5.3.0 for x386 with -Os compiles this to 1280 bytes
#include <stdint.h>

// hash len bytes in memory pointed by ibuf
void tinysha256(
    uint8_t         hash[32],           // result
    const uint8_t * data,               // input
    uint32_t        size                // input size
    )
    {
    uint32_t s[8] = {                   // init state
        0x6a09e667,0xbb67ae85,0x3c6ef372,0xa54ff53a,0x510e527f,0x9b05688c,0x1f83d9ab,0x5be0cd19};
    uint32_t w[16];                     // data buffer
    uint32_t x;                         // warning about unitialized x can be safely ignored
    const uint8_t *e = data+size;       // end of data
    int n = 0;
    for(;;) {
        while (data!=e) {               // while there is data..
            x = (x<<8)+ *data++;        // accumulate it in x, big-endian
            if ((3&~n)==0) {            // a full 32-bit chunk
                w[n>>2] = x;
                if (n==63) {
                    n = 0;
                    goto c;             // compression
                    }
                }
            ++n;
            }
        switch(n) {                     // handle padding
        case 64:
            n = x = 0;
            break;
        case 65:
            n = 31;
            do
                hash[n] = s[n>>2]>>((3&~n)<<3);
            while(--n>=0);
            return;
        default:
            x = ((x<<8)|0x80)<<((3&~n)<<3);
            }
        w[n >>= 2] = x;
        while (++n!=14) {
            if (n==16) {                // extra compression needed
                n = 64;
                goto c; 
                }
            w[n] = 0;
            }
        w[14] = (uint32_t)(size>>29);   // length padding
        w[15] = (uint32_t)(size<< 3);
        n = 65;
c:          {                           // compression
            static const uint32_t k[64] = {
                0x428a2f98,0x71374491,0xb5c0fbcf,0xe9b5dba5,0x3956c25b,0x59f111f1,0x923f82a4,0xab1c5ed5,
                0xd807aa98,0x12835b01,0x243185be,0x550c7dc3,0x72be5d74,0x80deb1fe,0x9bdc06a7,0xc19bf174,
                0xe49b69c1,0xefbe4786,0x0fc19dc6,0x240ca1cc,0x2de92c6f,0x4a7484aa,0x5cb0a9dc,0x76f988da,
                0x983e5152,0xa831c66d,0xb00327c8,0xbf597fc7,0xc6e00bf3,0xd5a79147,0x06ca6351,0x14292967,
                0x27b70a85,0x2e1b2138,0x4d2c6dfc,0x53380d13,0x650a7354,0x766a0abb,0x81c2c92e,0x92722c85,
                0xa2bfe8a1,0xa81a664b,0xc24b8b70,0xc76c51a3,0xd192e819,0xd6990624,0xf40e3585,0x106aa070,
                0x19a4c116,0x1e376c08,0x2748774c,0x34b0bcb5,0x391c0cb3,0x4ed8aa4a,0x5b9cca4f,0x682e6ff3,
                0x748f82ee,0x78a5636f,0x84c87814,0x8cc70208,0x90befffa,0xa4506ceb,0xbef9a3f7,0xc67178f2
                };
            uint32_t r[8];
            int j = 7;
            do
                r[j] = s[j];
            while (--j>=0);         
            j = 0;
            do
                {
#define RL(value, bits) (((value) << (bits)) | ((value) >> (32 - (bits))))
#define S0(x)   (RL((x),30)^RL((x),19)^RL((x),10))
#define S1(x)   (RL((x),26)^RL((x),21)^RL((x),7))
#define S2(x)   (RL((x),25)^RL((x),14)^((x)>>3))
#define S3(x)   (RL((x),15)^RL((x),13)^((x)>>10))
#define S4(x,y,z) ((z)^((x)&((y)^(z))))
#define S5(x,y,z) (((x)&(y))^((z)&((x)^(y))))
                uint32_t t = r[7] + S1(r[4]) + S4(r[4], r[5], r[6]) + k[j] + w[j&15];
                r[7] = r[6]; r[6] = r[5]; r[5] = r[4]; r[4] = r[3] + t;
                r[3] = r[2]; r[2] = r[1]; r[1] = r[0]; r[0] = t + S0(r[1]) + S5(r[1], r[2], r[3]);
                w[j&15] += S3(w[(j+14)&15]) + w[(j+9)&15] + S2(w[(j+1)&15]);     
                }
            while(++j!=64);
            j = 7;
            do
                s[j] += r[j];
            while (--j>=0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Let's call the scheme that reserves some bits FMECDSA :) Nice to see my ideas/comments reflected in this extensive answer. Note that usually there is also a bit reserved for the Y coordinate (compressed encoding), but just verifying / using the X coordinate is often used. It's not like an adversary can generate a private key for the X coordinate. So it *looks* secure at least.

Comment: I know this is a long shot, but do you have any references where I could find a hashing algorithm with less than 1kB of code? Every implementation of common SHAs I find usually use up multiple kB, which I can't afford.

Comment: @Sossenbinder: MurmurHash is not a cryptographic hash, thus is squarely unsuitable. Use a standard hash! I have now included a size-optimized implementation of SHA-256 (1.2 kiB)

Comment: Thank you a lot, I'm going to try this right now! Any copyright limitations I should be aware of?

Comment: Done. Thanks. I found a similar algorithm with about the same code size, but it requires much more RAM, which is even more limited on my system. This works really well

Comment: Another long shot, is there any source for this code? I would like to use it for some thesis work, but I would like to include a link to a source as wlel

Comment: @Sossenbinder: I'd be OK with _public domain code written by fgrieu_, `https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/48722/12` (this URL should have stable content; I reserve to further trim downn or otherwise improve the code).