# secp521r1 elliptic curve base point coordinates

Tags: elliptic-curves

According to Standards Recommanded Elliptic Curve parameter for Cryptography, for each given curve, the base point is given in compressed and uncompressed form, but personnaly I do not understand how to use it with that form, I need the (X,Y) coordinates for my application, thanks to show me how to find them from the given form.

Comment: Why are you using secp521r1 and not Curve25519 or Curve448, or their analogous twisted Edwards curves, or, if you really insist on a ‘256-bit’ security level using an admittedly awesome Mersenne prime, E-521?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compressed form of the base point only provides the X coordinate. It is identified by a leading $\mathtt{02}$ or $\mathtt{03}$ byte. The remaining bytes are the hex-encoded X coordinate. Y can be recovered using the curve definition $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b \pmod{p}$. As both Y and -Y can satisfy the equation, the leading $\mathtt{02}$ indicates the that the positive value should be taken, and the leading $\mathtt{03}$ indicates that the negative value should be taken. You can read more details in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8914/ecdsa-compressed-public-key-point-back-to-uncompressed-public-key-point).

The uncompressed form of the base point provides both the X and Y coordinates. It is identified by the leading $\mathtt{04}$ byte. The remaining bytes are the hex-encoded X and Y coordinates, concatenated as X || Y.

Looking at [SEC2 Ver1](http://www.secg.org/SEC2-Ver-1.0.pdf), "**2.9.1 Recommended Parameters secp521r1**", we have:

> ```
> G =       04 00C6858E 06B70404 E9CD9E3E CB662395 B4429C64 8139053F  
>     B521F828 AF606B4D 3DBAA14B 5E77EFE7 5928FE1D C127A2FF A8DE3348  
>     B3C1856A 429BF97E 7E31C2E5 BD660118 39296A78 9A3BC004 5C8A5FB4  
>     2C7D1BD9 98F54449 579B4468 17AFBD17 273E662C 97EE7299 5EF42640  
>     C550B901 3FAD0761 353C7086 A272C240 88BE9476 9FD16650
> ```

In other words, the uncompressed encoding of the basepoint `G = 04 || X || Y`. Using that we can parse the coordinates of `G` as:

> ```
> X =     00C6 858E06B7 0404E9CD 9E3ECB66 2395B442 9C648139 053FB521
>     F828AF60 6B4D3DBA A14B5E77 EFE75928 FE1DC127 A2FFA8DE 3348B3C1
>     856A429B F97E7E31 C2E5BD66
> Y =     0118 39296A78 9A3BC004 5C8A5FB4 2C7D1BD9 98F54449 579B4468
>     17AFBD17 273E662C 97EE7299 5EF42640 C550B901 3FAD0761 353C7086
>     A272C240 88BE9476 9FD16650
> ```